# Selenium getting attribute/ CSS / property

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the scenario where selenium needs to open the login form and immediately after the page was loaded, click the "Log in" without entering anything. When nothing is filled the fields are both:

- Surrounds are highlighted to red
- Field name color changed is changed to red
- "Required" string appears at the bottom of the field

I've got the whole test running, fields are located but I have no idea how to check (those point) correctly.

**DOM only for one field** (for the non-red form) is completely ugly:

```
<div class="form-row" xpath="1">
   <div class="jss98 jss99 primary input outlined-input" input="[object Object]" meta="[object Object]">
      <label class="jss113 jss102 jss107 jss110 jss112" data-shrink="false" for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="jss133 jss120 jss134">
         <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss150 jss127" style="padding-left: 29.25px;">
            <legend class="jss151" style="width: 0.01px;"><span>​</span></legend>
         </fieldset>
         <input aria-invalid="false" class="jss143 jss128" id="email" type="text" value="" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**DOM with "red":**

```
<div class="form-row" xpath="1">
   <div class="jss98 jss99 primary input outlined-input error " input="[object Object]" meta="[object Object]" aria-describedby="email-helper-text">
      <label class="jss113 jss116 jss105 jss102 jss107 jss110 jss112" data-shrink="false" for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="jss133 jss120 jss139 jss125 jss134">
         <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss150 jss127" style="padding-left: 29.25px;">
            <legend class="jss151" style="width: 0.01px;"><span>​</span></legend>
         </fieldset>
         <input aria-invalid="true" class="jss143 jss128" id="email" type="text" value="" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;">
      </div>
      <p class="jss159 jss163 jss160" id="email-helper-text">Required</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

We can see that: "class="jss98 jss99 primary input outlined-input error"/ aria-describedby="email-helper-text", input aria-invalid="true" and finally new paragraph was added with the text "Required"

What I would like to do right now is to check the field BEFORE it was clicked and check if those things listed above are nulls, next click and check if the elements previously not present are now present.

Could someone explain me how those three methods enclosed in the title are vary?

I would like to take the value? of class inside the div (class="jss98 jss99 primary input outlined-input"). Can someone tell me how it can be taken?

**I'm writing in C#**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you would want to do is put the before and after HTML in a diff engine to see what changed. (You can find a simple one online if you don't have one already.) There are three things I see (that I think are significant):

1. The class "error" is added to the outer `DIV`
2. The "aria-invalid" attribute on the `INPUT` changes from `false` to `true`
3. The `P` tag is added with id="email-helper-text" and contains "Required"

The before and after tests would go something like this... you do a `.FindElements()` (plural) and see if the count is 0 before and 1 after.

Here are some code samples

Example 1

```
By errorClassLocator = By.CssSelector("div.outlined-input.error");

// before
Assert.Zero(Driver.FindElements(errorClassLocator).Count, "Verify that 'error' class is not present");

// after
Assert.NotZero(Driver.FindElements(errorClassLocator).Count, "Verify that 'error' class is present");
```

Example 2

```
By ariaInvalidLocator = By.CssSelector("input#email[aria-invalid='true']");

// before
Assert.Zero(Driver.FindElements(ariaInvalidLocator).Count, "Verify that 'aria-invalid' attribute value of 'true' is not present");

// after
Assert.NotZero(Driver.FindElements(ariaInvalidLocator).Count, "Verify that 'aria-invalid' attribute is true");
```

NOTE: You could also use two locators... look for aria-invalid='false' for before instead of 'true' doesn't exist. Another option would be to find the element and then pull the value of 'aria-invalid' and compare it to 'true' or 'false'.

Example 3

```
By requiredLocator = By.Id("email-helper-text");

// before
Assert.Zero(Driver.FindElements(requiredLocator).Count, "Verify that the 'email-helper-text' P is not present");

// after
Assert.NotZero(Driver.FindElements(requiredLocator).Count, "Verify that the 'email-helper-text' P is present");
Assert.AreEqual("Required", Driver.FindElement(requiredLocator).Text, "Verify that 'Required' text is present");
```

NOTE: Using `.FindElements()` is crucial for the before case because if you use `.FindElement()` it will throw if the element is not found. It's also useful for the after case in case it's not present as expected. Instead of getting an `ElementNotFoundException`, you'll instead get a failed Assert with a clear message on what is missing.

Comment: Thanks for such an extended answer, will test it and let you know about the results :)

Answer (score 1):

You could basically use XPath to check for the contents of the class attribute like this:

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'error')]"
```

This should find nothing before you submit and find the colored element after submit.

Comment: Well if I try to find it inside DOM it will return no such element exception probably.